# AngularJS 2 - Using HTTP Wrapper - Getting "No Provider!" Error

Tags: angular, typescript

For one of our projects, I need to use an HTTP wrapper that will send an authorisation header with every request. However, upon loading the page with `npm start`, I get the following error in console:

`EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.html:2:2 caused by: No provider for HttpClient!
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for HttpClient!`

Note: for the sake of not pasting all the code, I use dots ("...") to represent "self-explanatory" things such as importing the core libraries, etc.
I'm also using "placeholder" to replace names that I cannot disclose.

For the wrapper I'm using, I found the following:

**http.wrapper.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
   ...
}
```

In my API service, I do the following to make use of the HTTP wrapper:

**api.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { HttpClient } from '../http.wrapper';

@Injectable
export class APIService implements OnInit {
   ...

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

   getActiveScenarios(): Observable<Scenario[]> { ... }
}
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
...
import { HttpClient } from './common/http.wrapper';
import { MyModule } from './placeholder/my-module.module';
...

@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, MyModule],
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   exports: [AppComponent, BrowserModule],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**my-module.component.ts**:

```
import { ApiService } from '../placeholder/services/api.service';

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'placeholder',
   templateUrl: './my-module.component.html',
   providers: [ ApiService ]
})
export class MyModuleComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

   ngOnInit() {}

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `HttpClient` to module's list of providers to register it with the injector.

#### app.module.ts

```
...
import { HttpClient } from './common/http.wrapper';
import { MyModule } from './placeholder/my-module.module';
...

@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, MyModule],
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   exports: [AppComponent, BrowserModule],
   providers: [HttpClient],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll accept this as the answer. It would seem that adding that to the providers and adding HttpModule (suggested by Günther Zöchbauer) to imports made it work. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `HttpModule`

```
imports: [BrowserModule, MyModule, HttpModule],
```

to make `HttpClient` available.

Comment: Thank you for the very swift response. I've tried both putting it there and in bootstrap, but it still says the same thing.

Comment: That's all that's needed. Can you reproduce the problem in a Plunker?

Comment: I forgot to mention your name in the other reply, but it seems that doing both what you suggested, as well as putting HttpClient in the list of providers, is what made it work now. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `HttpClient` to `providers`. If you need this, you're doing something wrong. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html